# How do I install Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-drive

I have a laptop that has Ubuntu for about 3 years and now I want to dual boot my computer with Windows 10.

Now, I'm trying to burn Windows to a pendrive, but when I boot my computer, it doesn't detect that I have a pendrive attached. I have formated it a million times (most of the times I formatted it to FAT, but I tried NTFS and Ext4).

What's confusing for me is that I have used the very same pendrive to boot other distros from and it worked. I even tried it yesterday, when wanted to test if it works with other Linux distros, it did. So I have no idea at this point.

Also I heard that installing Windows after Ubuntu could break Linux, but I should not worry about that, because I can fix that, right?

I would really appriciate some help right now! Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: "Now, I'm trying to burn Windows to a pendrive, but when I boot my computer, it doesn't detect that I have a pendrive attached."  Not an Ubuntu problem; at most a problem with your hardware or BIOS. Some systems boot by themself of an USB, others you need to set up and others you need to explicitly select it from BIOS. " I have formated it a million times" If true the USB is dead. It does not have that kind of lifespan.

Comment: 1. You can use mkusb to create a Windows install drive. See this link, [mkusb-nox and mkusb version 12 can create Windows install drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380); 2. Make your computer boot from the USB drive; 3. Install Windows; 4. Repair the grub bootloader.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS hardware? UEFI or BIOS install of Ubuntu? Drives MBR or gpt? All those will make a difference on how you boot install media and then install system.